# tutorial of integrating vk in android application

Tags: java, android, eclipse, vk

I want to integrate vk with my android application but do not get enough resource . I have find the following tutorial and am trying to follow the instructions . 
[Vk Tutorial](https://github.com/thest1/Android-VKontakte-SDK) .

The instruction is following :

Quickly understand the principles of the library will help you demo project AndroidVkSdkSample. It is implemented and the authorization as an example of shipping records your wall. 
To connect the library to the project, perform the following steps:

1. Import project AndroidVkSdk in Eclipse. AndroidVkSdk implemented as Android Library Project.
2. Add to your project a reference to AndroidVkSdk.
3. Make sure that your application has permission to access the Internet

1. Create a login url and open it in WebView

   String  url = Auth . getUrl ( API_ID ,  Auth . getSettings ()); 
   Webview . loadURL ( url );

Here as API_ID ID must be specified in your application that you created in http://vk.com/developers.php

1. Webview wait to be redirected to Auth.redirect_url. Parse redirect_url to get out of it access_token. For example, see how it's done in the project LoginActivity.java AndroidVkSdkSample.
2. Create Object Api for querying the server VKontakte:
   API  api = New  Api ( access_token ,  API_ID );
3. Now you can query the server, such as:

   ```
   api . createWallPost ( user_id ,  text ,  null ,  null ,  false ,  false ,  false ,  null ,  null );
   ```

My trying :

I have imported the  AndroidVkSdk in Eclipse . But in eclipse the following error is showing ."[2014-02-20 18:06:29 - AndroidVkSdk] ERROR: resource directory 'H:\App\Android-VKontakte-SDK-master\AndroidVkSdk\res' does not exist" . Why ? Can you help me ? I will be very helpful if you provide me tutorial for integrating vk or give me some tips to remove this error .

Comment: make sure you imported correct directory. maybe you need to import `H:\App\Android-VKontakte-SDK-master\AndroidVkSdk` ? or maybe you have to prepare `res` folder and move sdk contents into it

Comment: ah, i guess the library looks like a usual Android project folder, with `src`, `res` etc. so if there is no `res` folder, you may create empty one and see what happens

Comment: ok . Please see this question . http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21910928/error-in-posting-status-in-vk